# Можно ли в Python присвоить переменной вызов функции?

Tags: python

В командной строке Windows для очистки вывода используется команда `cls`.
Для того, чтобы очистить вывод интерпретатора, вызванного в командной строке, нужно уже прописывать такой код:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('cls')
```

Это можно упростить, создав функцию:

```
>>> def cls():
...     os.system('cls')
...
>>>
```

И вызывать ее уже вот так: `>>> cls()`

Но все же хотелось бы как-то добиться нужного результата именно командой `cls`, без скобок от функции.

Первое, что пришло в голову - присвоить вызов функции переменной. Но это, к сожалению, не работает :(

**Как можно реализовать мою идею?** *Если можно вообще...*

---

*Вот попытки присвоения вызова функции переменной, ниже их результат.*

```
>>> cls = lambda: cls()
```

```
>>> cls
<function <lambda> at 0x01D76D60>
```

---

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> cls = partial(clr)
```

```
>>> cls
functools.partial(<function cls at 0x01CA7778>)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно переопределить `__repr__`. Именно этот метод вызывается когда нужно показать значение объекта в виде строки.

Приблизительно так:

```
class CLS:
    def __repr__(self):
        os.system('cls')
        return ''


cls = CLS()
```

Теперь ввод одного лишь `cls` в командную строку будет вызывать `CLS.__repr__`.